# The following error java.lang.NullPointerException is displayed after run the project

Tags: java, selenium, testng

**Problem**:
My classes are Hooks for setup and test. I try to click on cookie pop-up, using WebdriverWait, but don't work. I have no idea why.

I am a beginner with selenium and automation testing and I am writing a selenium script using java, TestNG, and maven. When I write everything in one class, all works fine, but I want to have a package for all objects, a package for tests, and Hooks with the main setting.
**What I do**
public class Hooks
{
public WebDriver driver;
@BeforeMethod
public void Setup() throws InterruptedException
{
//set property for driver, Firefox instance
System.setProperty("webdriver.driver.firefox", "C://SeleniumWebdrivers//chromedriver.exe");
//create driver object
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//Maximize page
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//implicit wait
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://google.com/");
//scroll
//        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,600)");
}

```
    @AfterMethod
    public void TearDown(){
       driver.quit();

    }
```

For test

```
public class Tests extends Hooks{
    @Test
    public void Test() throws InterruptedException{
        //Arrange
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        //Act
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click();
    
        //Assert
        Assert.assertEquals("EVALUAREA APARATULUI LOCOMOTOR", "EVALUAREA APARATULUI LOCOMOTOR")
    }
```

And the errors are:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at Tests.Test(Tests.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

How can I fix these errors and why do they occur?

**What I tried:**
I tried to add Hooks class, I added different properties for my class

Comment: What is `HomePage` class ? what constructor it has ? Attach screenshot of Package structure . Additionally `System.setProperty` is wrongly set up, you have chromedriver exe for firefox instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the same answer as rzwitserloot gave but in a different order.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The stack trace complains about a `NullPointerException`. This means that a reference that should have pointed to an object was not pointing to anything (i.e. the reference was null).

So why was it null? For that you have to look at the next part of the stack trace. Each line describes a method. Each time a new method is called inside another a line is added. The format is `<package>.<class>.<method>(<file:line>)`.

```
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at Tests.Test(Tests.java:15)
```

So the first few lines aren't your code. The first line is from java, the other ones are from selenium. Your code starts at `Tests.Test(Tests.java:15)`.

So what happens at this line?

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6000);
```

At this line you are creating a new instance of `WebDriverWait`. You pass two arguments to the constructor. The second one is a number and clearly not null. The first one `driver` is a reference to a `WebDriver`. Because the other argument can't be null, this one probebly is.

So why would `driver` be `null`?

You've declared the `driver` a field in the `Hooks` class. And by default if you don't assign a value when declaring the field it's value is null.

```java
public class Hooks
{
    public WebDriver driver;
```

So problem located.

But you say, you are giving `driver` a value in the `Setup` method!

```java
public class Hooks
{
    public WebDriver driver;
   @BeforeMethod
    public void Setup() throws InterruptedException
    {
        ...
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        ...
    }
```

Because you've added `WebDriver` before `driver = new ChromeDriver();` it means you've created a local variable with the same name as the class field `driver`. Because local variables are more important then class fields the `driver` name in the `Setup` method now only refers to the local variable.

To assign the driver to the field you can either use `this.driver = driver` after creating the new `ChromeDriver`. Or you can remove `WebDriver` and only write `driver = new ChromeDriver();` to assign the new `ChromeDriver` to the class field.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

> `public WebDriver driver;`

This declares a field, named `driver`. Not sure why you made it public.

> `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

This declares a **local variable**, also named `driver`, which is **completely unrelated** to the field you declared. As all local variables go, it ceases to exist when the method you declared it in ends. Because it has the same name, referencing variable `driver` in this method refers to the local variable and not the field.

All you really wanted was to make that second line:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

as that would set the field, instead of declaring a new local variable and initializing it.

This problem has nothing to do with testing, it's just basic java stuff.

Comment: Hey man, be kind. This looks like this is a some who's new to programming in general. Beginners don't usually know the difference between basic java stuff and everything else because it's *all* complicated.